# How to get the User.Identity information in the Middleware during the /connect/authorize call when the user still has authentication cookies?

Tags: c#, identityserver4, openid-connect, openid, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a problem with my Middleware that the user identity is always empty because the user can access the page with their authentification cookies.

This middleware is to check and do the redirection to a specific page if the condition is fullfiled.

I give my code as below :

```
        app.Use(async (httpContext, next) =>
        {
            string token = httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

            if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var userId = httpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "sub");
                var claim = httpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == Admin.BusinessLogic.Identity.Dtos.Enums.Key4ClaimTypes.IsRedirect.ToString());
                if (
                        claim == null
                        ||
                        (claim != null && claim.Value.ToLower() != "true")
                    )
                {
                    var registrationBehavior = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(RegistrationBehavior)).Get<RegistrationBehavior>();
                    var reqUrl = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.UriHelper.GetEncodedUrl(httpContext.Request);
                    var returnUrl = string.Format("{0}?identityUserId={1}&returnUrl={2}", registrationBehavior.PageRedirectUrl, userId?.Value, System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(reqUrl));

                    httpContext.Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
            }

            //// Move forward into the pipeline
            await next();

        });
```

Could someone give me an idea or an example to be able get this user identity information?

I guess this is related to the authentication cookie.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your middleware after the app.UseAuthentication() part in your request pipeline, otherwise the User object will be empty.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Yes, I did that. The problem is the client call directly le /connect/authorize from the browser with their authentication cookie. So they will not pass any [Authorize] or [AllowAnonymous] from the IS website.